# Pointer in function to linked list not updating element in 1 case

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am using a struct like this

```
struct infoM {
 char* direction;
 int key;
};

typedef struct nodeM{
    struct infoM nodeInfo;
    struct nodeM *next;
    struct nodeM *prev;
} node;

typedef node list;
```

I have one function that returns the wanted node by a specific field

```
node * search(list *l, char* direction) {}
```

And this is my function to remove elements from the list

```
  int delete(list *l, char* direction) {
node *tmp = search(l, direction);
if (tmp != NULL) {
    node *ant = tmp->prev;
    node *seg = tmp->next;

    if (seg != NULL) {

        if (ant != NULL) {  
            ant->next = seg;
            seg->prev = ant;
            free(tmp);
            return 1;
        } else { //prev null
            seg->prev = NULL;
            *l = *seg;
            tmp = NULL;
            free(tmp);
            return 1;
        }
    } else { //next null
        if (ant == NULL) { 
            l->nodeInfo.key = somevalue;
            l->next = NULL;
            l->prev = NULL;
            return 1;
        } else {
            printf("Here is the problem\n");
            ant->next = NULL;
            free(tmp);
            return 1;
        }
    }
} else { //tmp nulo
    perror("Error delete : node null\n");
    return 0;
}
}
```

If I have 4 elements in the list, 1234 and I delete first first element everything is okay and returns 234. If I delete the last element it returns 23 seems to work great. But if I try to delete the last element now the function does nothing despite being the same case that when it is 234 and I don't understand why. The list is not being updated.

In the main I am using the list like this :

```
 list a;
 delete(&a, "whatever");
```

What am I doing wrong ?

This is the code for search

```
node * createnode(){
node *tmp = (node *) malloc (sizeof(node));
return tmp;
}



node * search(list *l, char* direction) {
node *tmp = createnode();   

if (l->nodeInfo.key == 777) {
    perror("Error search: empty list\n");
    return NULL;
}

tmp=l;

while((strcmp(direction, tmp->nodeInfo.direction) !=0) && (tmp->next != NULL)) {
    tmp = tmp->next;
}

if (strcmp(direction, tmp->nodeInfo.direction) == 0) {
    return tmp;
} else {
    perror("Error search: element not found\n");
    return NULL;
}
}
```

Comment: please enclose the code for `search`.

Comment: code updated with search and createnode

Comment: What does this sequence do: `tmp = NULL; free(tmp);` What does this statement do `*l = *seg`? Please explain as thoroughly as you can. Hint: the last one is masking a fatal design error. Use your debugger to look at the list. Do you have, for each node `n`, `n == n->next->prev` and  `n == n->prev->next`?

Comment: The first sequence is because if i do free(tmp) directly I get an error. *l= *seg updates the first element of the list, if i do l=tmp it doesn't work. In the case where I am getting the error it's mainly because I want to modify "l" but only tmp is being modified. So the update doesnt leave the function. But when I have 234 it does , so I don't understand why in that case it works and when I have 2,3 it doesn't. Note that it only fails after deleting the elements in the order I have mentioned, in other orders works apparently.

Comment: First sequence: I'm asking *what* it does, not *why* you put it there or which other variants don't do what you want them to do. *What does this code do?* What is the net result of executing it?

Comment: Second sequence: *\*l= \*seg updates the first element of the list.* Can you draw the list before and after the update? Use something like [this format](http://commoninterview.com/images/Double-Linked-List.jpg), also show where `l` and `tmp` are pointing.

Comment: Okay here are the pictures. [Pic1](http://i.imgur.com/d9zzi7e.png)  [Pic2](http://i.imgur.com/HZlUU8v.png)

Comment: The pictures look like they are generated by ddd. They are misleading. Note how `tmp` and `l` pointers have the same value, but ddd draws `*tmp` and `*l` as if they were separate objects. There are also no back pointers shown as arrows. FYI, if you don't tag the user you are talking to, like this: @asdfasdfwe, they may or may not see your comments.

Comment: Hope this works, else tell me what debugger I should use to show you the values @n.m. [Pic1](http://i.imgur.com/UIO6vE7.jpg) [Pic2](http://i.imgur.com/r3c5vaP.jpg)

Comment: pic2 is what you want to happen, but does it really happen? Look at your previous pic2. There you have l==tmp==0xbffff028, but seg==0x804b440, a different node. The second node in the list (key 3) points back to 0x804b440, one that seg points to, but not one that l points to. What is that 0x804b440 node? Where does it go to when the function ends?

Comment: Okay I understand what you mean. You are right, looks like *l=*seg is one of the problems. [Pic1](http://i.imgur.com/V8ppFOP.png) - [Result](http://i.imgur.com/6zMP5iE.png). So what I wanted to do is l=seg which leads me to the real problem I have. How can I modify what "l" is pointing to ? [After fixing to l=seg](http://i.imgur.com/mY8FwN8.png) - [Issue](http://i.imgur.com/M0i90nB.png). By the way @n.m. thank you for being so patient and helping me out. This is not very common nowadays.

Comment: You are doing great. Now you have to decide how to represent an empty list. Your `typedef node list;` cannot do the job. An empty list has *no* nodes.  Perhaps `typedef node* list;` is better. A NULL pointer would be an empty list. So you create an empty list like this: `list a = NULL;` You will still have `int delete(list *l, char* direction)`, but what happens inside will have to change because `l` now is not a pointer to a node but *a pointer to a pointer* to a node. You will still have `*l = (something)` inside; that's how you modify what the head of the list is pointing to. Good luck.

Comment: So that's why most of the people use a pointer to the struct, I get it now. Thank you for all @n.m.